# How to make accept button for cookies?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to create accept button to allow cookies and close popup dialog 
I also want close button if users don't want cookies. 
But don't know how. 
I used different codes from durgi sites to pair it with my but nothing happens. I do not have much Javascript experience, so I'll ask for help.
I tried different methods, but all were unsuccessful.
Please help me.

```js
function openPopup() {
      window.location.hash = 'popup1';
    }
    
    window.onload = openPopup;
```

```css
.box {
      width: 40%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
      padding: 35px;
      border: 2px solid #fff;
      border-radius: 20px/50px;
      background-clip: padding-box;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .overlay {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      transition: opacity 500ms;
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    .overlay:target {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .popup {
      margin: 70px auto;
      padding: 20px;
      background: #fff;
      border-radius: 5px;
      width: 30%;
      position: relative;
      transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
      top:120px;
    }
    
    .popup h2 {
      margin-top: 0;
      color: #333;
      font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    .popup .close {
      position: absolute;
      top: 20px;
      right: 30px;
      transition: all 200ms;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #333;
    }
    .popup .close:hover {
      color: #06D85F;
    }
    .popup .content {
      max-height: 30%;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 700px){
      .box{
        width: 70%;
      }
      .popup{
        width: 70%;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div id="popup1" class="overlay" >
     <div class="popup">
      <h2>Here i am</h2>
      <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
      <div class="content">
       Thank to pop me out of that button, but now i'm done so you can close this window.
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg center-block" > OK. Let's go! </button>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to find out what kind of questions Stack Overflow [is](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) intended for.

Comment: You have a function that activates the dialog. Now you need an event that is triggered when clicking on the close button, that closes the dialog again

Comment: Your main issue is with show/hide the alert/popup or with the PHP cookies logic?

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, I think you are trying to create "Accept Cookie Policy" Popup.

So here is my solution with comment Inline, I have used jQuery for this solution.

```
// Check if localstorage is present or not in the browser
// If localstorage is not present you can use cookies as well to achieve this
// or you can send a call to the server to manage this 
if (window.localStorage) {
  // Check if the user is already accepted the cookie policy
  if (!localStorage.getItem("userAgreed")) {
    jQuery("#popup1").show();
  } else {
    jQuery("#popup1").hide();
  }
}

// Handle Ok button click, and set a localstorage key-value pair the user is accepted the cookie popup
// So that from the next time onwards popup is not visible to returning user
jQuery("#popup1 button").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Make a server call if you want to handle it in server side here
  localStorage.setItem("userAgreed", true);
  jQuery("#popup1").hide();
});

// On click of close button
jQuery("#popup1 a.close").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  jQuery("#popup1").hide();
});
```

Let me know if it's helping or not